# Can't seem to search just first line of text

Tags: unix, awk, find, aix

I'm using the following to only search the first line of a file for the report name. It's searching the whole file instead. I thought NR==1 would only search the first line. I think I just have a bad syntax.

```
find /SYM/SYM000/REPORT/ -type f -mmin -480 \
  -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
  -exec awk '/My Report Title/,NR==1 {print FILENAME; exit}' {} \;
```

Any help is appreciated.

I just want to return the filename. It looks for the past eight hours with a 6 digit number as the filename mask.

Comment: If all you want is the filename, why search inside the file with `awk`?  Find's `-print` option will print the filename.

Comment: it should be `/My Report Title/ && NR==1`

Comment: The title is in the first line that's why I needed awk. Thanks hek2mgl that worked perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[hek2gml's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35727363/45375) contains the crucial pointer - you **must use `&&` for logical AND** rather than a *range* - but the command can be made more efficient in two respects:

- Short-circuit processing of a given input file so that processing stops after the first line.
- Passing (typically) *all* files to a *single* `awk` call, by terminating the `-exec` primary with `+` rather than `\;`

```
find /SYM/SYM000/REPORT/ -type f -mmin -480 \
  -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
  -exec awk '/My Report Title/ { print FILENAME } { nextfile }' {} +
```

This command only ever looks at the 1st line of each input file.

---

`nextfile` is not strictly POSIX-compliant, so if your `awk` doesn't have it (GNU Awk, Mawk, and BSD/OSX Awk do - not sure about AIX), use (less efficient, because it must read all lines of each file):

```
find /SYM/SYM000/REPORT/ -type f -mmin -480 \
  -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
  -exec awk 'FNR == 1 && /My Report Title/ { print FILENAME }' {} +
```

If, in the absence of `nextfile`, you'd rather call `awk` *once for each file* (`-exec` terminator `\;`), as in the original solution attempt (reads only the first line of each file, but calls `awk` once for *each* file):

```
find /SYM/SYM000/REPORT/ -type f -mmin -480 \
  -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
  -exec awk '/My Report Title/ { print FILENAME } { exit }' \;
```

Comment: Without the `nextfile` command this makes the situation likely worse, since it would require to scan all lines of a file instead of just the first line. However, with the `nextfile` command it might show slightly better performance because `awk` will just get called as much as needed but not for every file. Anyway I doubt that `{} +` is portable at all. Had a look at a co-workers Apple, nope!

Comment: @hek2mgl: Yes, but that is offset by the efficiency of a _single_ `awk` invocation due to `+` - hard to tell which one is better in this scenario (depends on file size, disk speed, ...). `nextfile` is definitely the way to go, but I don't know if AIX's `awk` implementation has it. I've added the alternative solution with `\;` and (single-)file short-circuiting.

Comment: @EdMorton: `-exec ... \;` calls the command for _each_ file; `-exec ... +` calls it with _as many as will fit on a command line_ (typically, all; like `xargs`). I've added a `\;`-based alternative to my answer, in case `nextfile` isn't available. Overall, the most efficient combination is `nextfile` + `-exec ...+`.

Comment: I was wrong: I was missing the dot for the current folder on Apple which is default in GNU find. The `{} +` syntax works.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Yes, `-exec ...+` _is_ portable - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html

Comment: Can you use the `-exec ...+` construction in an alternative solution with `-exec grep -m1 '.*' {} \ | grep -q bin \; -print` ?

Comment: @WalterA: You cannot directly use a pipeline with `-exec` (you'd have to use something like `-exec sh -c '... | ... ' - {} \;`) - `-exec` can only call a single external utility, and there's no shell involved.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you assume that `/My Report Title/,NR==1` will be a kind of a list of conditions separated by a `,`. That assumption is wrong.

Right in this case would be to use the *logical AND* operator `&&` to concatenate the conditions:

```
find /SYM/SYM000/REPORT/ -type f -mmin -480 \
  -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
  -exec awk '/My Report Title/ && NR==1 {print FILENAME; exit}' {} \;
```